# importing and transforming many csv files

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr, readr

I am importing and transforming many files in an inefficient way. I was wondering if someone could show me a faster way using purr. The following code is what I tried, and it should give you the general pattern:

```
data_2013 <- read_csv("data_2013") %>%
clean_names() %>% # using the janitor package
mutate(year = "2013")

data_2014 <- read_csv("data_2014") %>%
clean_names() %>%
mutate(year = "2014")
```

With the years increasing by 1 (all the way up to 2019). I eventually join all these files, as the key variables are the same. But clearly the importing of the files is inefficient.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 5):

We can do this in a loop with `map`.  Loop on the file names, read with `read_csv`, clean the names, and create the 'year' column

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
library(readr)
library(janitor)

files <- paste0("data_", 2013:2019, ".csv")
lst1 <-  files %>%
           map(~ read_csv(.x)) %>%
             clean_names() %>%
             mutate(year = str_extract(., "\\d{4}"))
```

If the `list` output needs to be merged into a single dataframe

```
dat1 <- bind_rows(lst1, .id = 'grp')
```

---

In `base R`, this can be done with `lapply`

```
lst1 <- lapply(files, function(x) transform(read.csv(x), 
                year = sub("data_(\\d+)\\..*", "\\1", x)))
dat1 <- do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, lst, grp = seq_along(lst1)))
```